# product filters in layered navigation not working on category page

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, layered-navigation, category-products

I have created a category and shows a static block and products on this category by selecting the option "static block and products" in category settings.

it is showing static block contents and products but the layered navigation in left sidebar are not working FILTERS are not filtering the products.

There is an error in console is that the reason?

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://usatilea.nextmp.net/skin/frontend/base/default/js/lib/imagesloaded.js"

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://usatilea.nextmp.net/skin/frontend/base/default/js/app.js"

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://usatilea.nextmp.net/media/catalog/category/"

 Location { href="http://usatilea.nextmp.n...orcelain.html?color=134",  origin="http://usatilea.nextmp.net",  protocol="http:",  more...}
 porcela...lor=134 (line 2674)
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://usatilea.nextmp.net/usa-tiles/media/wysiwyg/09.png"
```

And my static block has this code in it:

```
      <?php
      $_categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories();
      if ($_categories->count()):
      $categorycount = 0;
      foreach ($_categories as $_category):

    if ($_category->getIsActive()):
        $cur_category =       Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
        $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
        $layer->setCurrentCategory($cur_category);
        $catName = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getName();
        if ($categorycount == 0) {
            $class = "first";
        } elseif ($categorycount == 3) {
            $class = "last";
        } else {
            $class = "";
        }

     ?>


        <li class="item <?= $class ?> sub-cat-items">
        <a href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->
        htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>"><img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$cur_category->getThumbnail() ?>" width="580" alt="<?php echo
        $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>" /></a>
        <h1><?php echo
        $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?></h1>
                    </li>


    <?php
    endif;
    if ($categorycount == 3) {
        $categorycount = 0;
        echo "</ul>\n\n<ul class=\"products-grid\">";
    } else {
        $categorycount++;
    }
      endforeach;
    endif;
    ?>
```

Please look at the code and tell me if i am doing anything wrong here is the category page link: [click here for category page](http://usatilea.nextmp.net/index.php/materials/porcelain.html)